# Create new contact in Salesforce CRM from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, automationstudio

I have a situation need to create new contacts in Salesforce CRM from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Extension. The Data Extension is getting updated every 24 hours from an external system.

Salesforce Marketing Cloud Automation needs to pick these new contacts from last 24 hours and create new contacts in Saleforce Contact Object.

Could anyone please suggest the best method to approach this situation?

Comment: Thank you Brad. What are Pros and Cons in each of the options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the clouds connected with Marketing Cloud Connector then you could inject records into a Journey and use the salesforce Contact widget to create a records in SF.

Other options:

Create an SSJS script to read from DE and create SF records using API (automate with Automation Studio)

You could also extract the DE and file transfer to SF.

If your were going to custom script something then this might be best done in SF rather than SFMC, and you could use the SFMC API to pull records from the DE.

Each option has pros and cons. My preference would be to script something in SF to retrieve records from the DE.

Journey Builder solution sounds easiest, you're going to have to out trust in Journey Builder and your design

Comment: Thank you @iManage. What are Pros and Cons in each of the options.